# JS: Can I call a function with same scope as caller or do macro-like behavior

Tags: javascript, function, scope, macros

I often have to check whether an object exists (or more commonly, whether the object structure exists deep enough) before storing something in it. I'm tired of doing things like this:

```js
obj ? null : obj = {};
obj[key] = value;
```

Since that first line is so common, it would be good to modularize it (e.g. make it a function). I'd like to be able to do this:

```js
ensureObj(obj);
obj[key] = value;
```

Better yet, overcast it because I more often need something like this:

```js
ensureObj(obj, [k1, k2, k3]);
obj[k1][k2][k3] = value;
```

Of course you can write a function which takes `obj` and does `obj ? null : obj = {};` but it will never do anything for you because you can't call `ensureObj(obj)` if `obj` doesn't exist.

If I could call a function and ensure it uses the same scope as where it's called from, that should do it -- it seems to me that macros are the language feature that would be just the thing for this, but I see macros don't exist in JS, though there are packages which simulate them for you. This doesn't (yet) work for me because my understanding is you're not actually writing JS, but something that gets compiled into JS -- which I can't insist the team move to without a much stronger reason.

So, without using something like `sweet.js`, is there a way I can modularize this test/prep process?

Comment: The null assignment operator makes it significantly less unpleasant to just write it in as needed: `obj ??= {}; obj[k1] ??= {}; obj[k1][k2] ??= {};`. It would be nice to have a standard library function, but that at least is not so bad.

Comment: Good to know -- I've not heard of this operator before -- but something isn't right. I tried `obj ??= {};` and it threw `Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined`.

Comment: The variable still has to be initialized `let obj;`. But for literals you wouldn't need it. Consider instead the case of a function parameter: `function foo(a) { let obj ??= a; /* do stuff */ }`. And you can see in my earlier comment how it helps with property assignments.

Comment: The whole point of my question is to ensure the object exists, when it's not been declared (not initialized either explicitly or implicitly). It's occurred to me that I could do something like `foo('obj', a)` if I want `obj` to be global, but not if I don't.

Comment: The only way to reference a symbol that may be uninitialized is to use the typeof operator, so there's no way to abstract it into a function. Your surmise is correct: you would need a macro to create the symbol in the current scope. But honestly, it's just easier all around to use object properties. It's stone simple to check if a property exists on an object, no macros, no nuthin. Have your possibly not-there things be object properties.

Comment: The more I work with JS, the more I see I should define a namespace (`window[myNameSpace]`) and store everything there - which would enable what you suggest. This would solve my need when I want a global variable, just not when I want to ensure `obj` exists in a local scope. Please put your comment (especially the first 2 sentences) as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Let me know if you need anything else on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to safely reference a symbol that may not exist is to use the `typeof` operator:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  // I'm on node.js
} else {
  // I'm in a browser
}
```

There's no way to abstract it into a function since you can't pass the possibly undeclared symbol as an argument, and there's no way to take a string and turn it into a valid identifier in the current scope.

So your surmise is correct. You would need a macro: a procedure that operates on the source code itself (or more precisely the AST it is parsed into). And while sweet.js is cool and all, it's usually better to look for a solution native to the language itself. Even when writing LISP I try not to reach for macros unless it's clear that nothing else will do.

Honestly, it's just easier all around in JS to use object properties. It's stone simple to check if a property exists on an object, no macros, no nuthin. Have your possibly not-there things be object properties. You can even do it with the global object:

```
if (!('foo' in globalThis)) globalThis.foo = whatever;
```

Although you should probably just use a regular object as a namespace as you yourself suggested in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, function calls are not like macros.

You can write a function that takes the new value to assign, and returns the object with it assigned:

```js
function assignObjectProperty(obj, [...keys], value) {
  if (!obj) {
    obj = {};
  }
  keys.reduce((o, k, index) => {
    if (index == keys.length - 1) {
      o[k] = value;
    } else if (!(typeof o[k] == 'object' && o[k] !== null)) {
      o[k] = {}
    }
    return o[k];
  }, obj);
  return obj;
}

let obj = null;
obj = assignObjectProperty(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3);
console.log(obj);

let obj1 = {x: 1, a: {z: 2}};
obj1 = assignObjectProperty(obj1, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3);
console.log(obj1);

let obj2 = {a: 2};
obj2 = assignObjectProperty(obj2, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3);
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: The conditional logic could be simplified by use of the [nullish coalescing assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) unless I'm missing something. Seems pretty widely supported now.

Comment: @JaredSmith I was originally doing something like that, but I needed to handle the case where the property exists but it has a non-object value, and replace it with an object.

Comment: @Barmar I've done something very like this and it works when `obj` exists but the structure isn't deep enough. But you can't call it when `obj` doesn't exist, and your first `if` is pointless -- hence my question. By putting `let obj = null;` before your function call, you've skipped over the point of the question. I explicitly cannot do that, because I'll erase anything already stored there.

Comment: Are you talking about trying to do something like `let obj = assignObjectProperty(obj, ...)`? Since you can't declare a variable multiple times, that doesn't really make sense. You could do `let obj = assignObjectProperty(null, ...)` and the object will be created by the first `if`.

Comment: @Barmar Often `obj` is created by other code, and I'm just adding to it. Sometimes `obj` needs to be rebuilt and so it's erased. If the code I'm writing is the first called to build/rebuild `obj`, then I need to ensure it exists before storing things in it. I want to avoid doing this all the time: `obj ? null : obj = {}; obj[k1] ? null : obj[k1] = {}; obj[k1][k2] = val;`. (I've already written code that ensures keys exist, but I can't do away with `obj ? null : obj = {};`).

Comment: So why can't you do this with my function? `obj = assignObjectProperty(obj, [k1, k2], val);`?